# Subdomain to default github pages domain

Tags: redirect, subdomain, github-pages

I communicated the wrong URL to many people for my github pages site:
I gave them the URL `https://www.[username].github.io` instead of `https://[username].github.io`...
I feel super dumb about it, but it's hard for me to notify the people of the change.
Is there a way to redirect `https://www.[username].github.io` to `https://[username].github.io` from the github pages projet ?

Or is there another way to fix this ?
Any help would be very welcome, I'm quite desperate here :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to be a plain "no". You have no control over the subdomain.

By the way, it is more or less a standard to redirect www.[...] to [...] it is a shame that github does not do it.
But there is no denial, the mistake was totally mine.